# Scheduled Power On/Off of 2nd HDD

Tags: hard-drive, power-management, backup, cron

im using a ubuntu 13.10 Server.
I want to switch off the 2nd HDD completely and only power it up once a week to back up the system+data from the 1st HDD.
I know how to use crontab, but I dont know how to switch off/on a HDD.

P.s. can you recommend a good incremental backup tool/script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hdparm` is probably what you want, it can control basically any aspect of your hard drives that you need. Invoked as `hdparm -S [value] /dev/hda` can control time until disk is put into standby/idle mode, and you should use the man page to check out other options you may find useful.

I use `rsync` to manage all my incremental backups over `ssh` to a remote server, and can thoroughly recommend it to you for backup purposes.